# Can I notify Twilio about the delivery/read status of a WhatsApp inbound message?

Tags: twilio, whatsapp

When my application receives inbound messages from WhatsApp users - is there a Twilio API which allows me to send "delivered" or "read" statuses back to the user initiating the conversation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The read recipes/blue checkmarks you have mentioned is currently not supported. Our team is continually working on improving and expanding our offerings for future updates.